# Magento - can a returning customer checkout without logging in?

Tags: checkout, login

something we get questions from returning customers that they can't place an order.

They forget to log-in with their account.

But is it possible to place an order for already existing customers, but without they have to log-in ...

Can any-one help with that?

Comment: Place on order for already existing customers... from the backend or frontend?

Comment: Its from front end

Answer (score 0):

You can increase the session time, this way they stay logged in longer.
Or use a special 'Cookie' to login as a extra feature they have to check (stay logged in).

- Make the page beter styled, so it's more obvious that you have to login.
- Disable guest account so they can't forget.
- Make your warning messages more clear and informative.
- Don't use one page checkout systems.

Warning: Only increase session time with SSL, because i have more time to go home after i sniffed there WiFi packages.